# How would I recreate the iOS send-text-message screen?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm writing an IRC client iOS application. I'd like my "Send Message" `UIViewController` to basically function exactly like the built-in iOS text messaging app's send message view. The view that I'm talking about, in particular, is the one you see when you open the `Messages` app, and click the "New Message" icon in the top-right. It looks like this:

[image]

### What this looks like to me:

This look like a `UIViewController` with a `UIToolbar` at the top. Beyond that, I can't figure out what the rest is. This does not look like a `UITableView`-based form, because I don't see empty row separators and the area does not let you drag it with your finger like you'd expect to see on a table view. So that looks like some kind of container, with a `UILabel`, `UITextField` and an image or button, for that plus sign.

The text area for typing looks like a `UITextView` inside of some kind of footer area that grows vertically until it reaches the bottom edge of the "To:" header, at which point the text area just begins to scroll, instead of expand.

The green behind the selected people's name. What is this, even? Is this a customized `UILabel`, or is that green most likely a graphical background image?

### What are these things, actually?

I'm a beginner at iOS development, so I'm not so keen at knowing what these things are. What components are used in this text messaging app? If that's not a table-based form, then what is it? How would I make something like that footer that sits on top of the keyboard like that, and grows until it reaches the top?

**To clarify, I do not need the actual chat bubble screen that occurs after this. I just would like to recreate this as a simple send message view. I do not need a pre-built package for the chat bubbles. I just need to recreate this appearance, really.**

Comment: I believe that in the question you linked, the user is asking more about the chat bubble and not necessarily the functionality and appearance before them, which is what I am after.

Comment: The two answers are links to open source chat clients that mimic the message screen you are after, you may in turn use either to implement to your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say exactly what Apple chose to use to implement each of those elements (I'm sure there are a number of ways to do some of them), but here's what I would suggest for each one:

**The recipients list**:

- A `UITextField` whose frame is constrained in between the recipient "bubbles" and the add button (and is resized every time a recipient is added)
- A set of custom `UIView` containers for each recipient "bubble", which contains a `UILabel` of the recipient name, overlaid on top of a stretchable `UIImageView` containing the green "bubble" underneath (see [this](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/08/stretchable-images-and-buttons/) for help on creating stretchable images)
- A `UIButton` for the add button
- All of this is contained inside a `UITableViewCell` (you likely wouldn't need / want to do this if you aren't planning to include the list of messages as well)

**The message field**:

- A `UITextView` for the textual input, whose frame is resized when a new line is added or removed, and starts scrolling when its size (plus the keyboard's size) reaches the top of the toolbar
- A `UIButton` for the send button
- A `UIButton` for the camera button
- All contained in a custom `UIView`, which is implemented as a footer at the bottom of the screen (but on top of the keyboard, of course)

Again, this is just a rough draft of how I would design it - this may not be the way Apple does it, and may not necessarily work in your use case.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has not provided any unified solution to this problem; I know because we faced much the same requirement in our app.  The Three20 framework did provide a solution, which we used at one time; but Three20 is apparently no longer maintained and it caused us so much trouble that we removed it from our build.

Eventually we built the view you are looking for (or something very similar) from scratch.  It was difficult and our code is still not pretty.  I would guess that Apple's code in the Messages and Mail apps is also not pretty, or they would have made it into an API.  Perhaps they will do it some day, but for now you have embrace the pain and do it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has not provided any unified solution to this problem; I know because we faced much the same requirement in our app.  The Three20 framework did provide a solution, which we used at one time; but Three20 is apparently no longer maintained and it caused us so much trouble that we removed it from our build.

Eventually we built the view you are looking for (or something very similar) from scratch.  It was difficult and our code is still not pretty.  I would guess that Apple's code in the Messages and Mail apps is also not pretty, or they would have made it into an API.  Perhaps they will do it some day, but for now you have embrace the pain and do it yourself.

UPDATE: Look here for another open-source solution.

http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/acanichat

I haven't evaluated it at all.